# What is the difference between a casez and a casex statement in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I know that a case statement in Verilog can start with case, casex, or casez. However, with casex and casez, when would I use one over the other?

Comment: What is preventing you from typing "casex vs casez" in google query?

Comment: You could also try a search for "verilog casex casez", just in case @EugeneSh. 's comment is deleted for being "unfriendly". We expect you to do a little research work before you ask a question here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson True friends are often speaking to each other in much harsher manner than that, so I wonder how "friendly" should be defined :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree with you, but I have had similar comments deleted.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Apparently StackExchange is now cracking down on comments that say "Just Google it..." However, I think Elliot has the _proper_ way of telling someone to Google an answer lol.

Comment: @KingDuken Yeah, saw it. Is it the whole SE or just StackOverflow?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well they posted it on the StackOverflow's blog but there has been a hyperlink to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) on every branch of SE the last couple of days, though I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are able to read the LRM, but are asking for an opinion: *Why*?

The problem is that many Verilog features were put in at the specific request of a user, and some of those features wound up not being that useful. And sometimes a feature was put in because it seemed consistent and easy to implement at the time, but in the end turned out to be counter-productive. `casex` might be one of those features. But much of this is lost history.

You should never use `casex`.  `casex` is [notorious](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf) for causing differences between pre- and post-synthesis simulations.

You use `casez` to model don't care conditions with a `?` in your case item. However, if you can move to SystemVerilog, the `case inside` statement is even better because it only looks at don't cares on the case item expression, not the case selection expression.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [ASIC World](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave2.html) for example codes.

---

### casez

Treats all the z values in the case expression as don't cares.

Example:

```
casez(opcode)
          4'b1zzx : begin // Don't care about lower 2:1 bit, bit 0 match with x
                      out = a; 
                      $display("@%0dns 4'b1zzx is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
                    end
          4'b01?? : begin
                      out = b; // bit 1:0 is don't care
                      $display("@%0dns 4'b01?? is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
                    end
          4'b001? : begin  // bit 0 is don't care
                      out = c;
                      $display("@%0dns 4'b001? is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
```

---

### casex

Treats all the x ***and*** z values in the case expression as don't cares.

Example:

```
 casex(opcode)
      4'b1zzx : begin // Don't care  2:0 bits
                  out = a; 
                  $display("@%0dns 4'b1zzx is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
                end
      4'b01?? : begin // bit 1:0 is don't care
                  out = b; 
                  $display("@%0dns 4'b01?? is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
                end
      4'b001? : begin // bit 0 is don't care
                  out = c;
                  $display("@%0dns 4'b001? is selected, opcode %b",$time,opcode);
                end
```

---

Of course you'll need an `endcase` at the end of both `casez` and `casex` modules.